# Cannot use javascript screen width inside css background image style also being set by javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Here is my code:

```
<div id="newprofileimg_<xsl:value-of select+"position()"/></div>
<script>
   var width=screen.width;
   var d=document.getElementById("newprofileimg_<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>");

   d.style.backgroundImage="url(/services/resizeimage/<xsl:value-of select="./mediaid"/>/"+width+"/500);";
</script>
```

The `backgroundImage` URL parses correctly, just for some reason the JavaScript isn't affecting the `div` being mutated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is nothing in your div, that's why the height of the div is 0px; You should add css to the div.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("test")
    div.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://via.placeholder.com/200/200')"
    div.style.width  = "200px"
    div.style.height = "200px"
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: can i apply the width and height of the div during the javascript? if i cant, wont that conflict with my background image resized image?

Comment: Yes you can I updated my answer, looks like height is 500px in your example and width is dynamic, use these variables in your code, by default div is a `block` element so you width is actually the width of the parent element, you just need to set up the height what is `500px`.